# Avoid c++ program from breaking with large inputs (cin)

Tags: c++, input, crash, cin, large-data

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
char test;
std::cin >> test;
std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
```

Hi, I want to make my program as userproof as possible, and this was just a test i was doing. When I input about 17,000 1's the program starts printing ¿ and keeps on printing ¿ whenever I press return.
I want to know if there is a way of stopping this inputs from breaking the program. Is it a problem with ctrl+V or with the size of the input? any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm using mac. so cmd + shift + v didn't copy anything. for our final project the teacher is going to make these sort of stress tests so i want to know if there is a way to handle them

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your C++ program (assuming at least one non-whitespace character's provided before EOF, would be better to have `if (std::cin >> test) std::cout << test << std::endl;`)  If there's a bug, it's going to be with your terminal or "clipboard" / Window Manager.  You could check what happens if you run `cat` then `control-V` to paste into the terminal then press `control`-`D` - does that echo the text back to the terminal properly?

Comment: I would recommend you to don't use std:: and instead use using namespace std; above the int main.